# How to make the scenario happen in batch script

Tags: multithreading, batch-file

```
@echo off

start COMMAND_ONE

for /f "tokens=1-6 delims=," %%i in ('type file1.txt') do (
  start COMMAND_TWO with arguments as %%i to %%n
)

for /f "tokens=1-6 delims=," %%i in ('type file2.txt') do (
  COMMAND_TWO with arguments as %%i to %%n
)

for /f "tokens=1-6 delims=," %%i in ('type file3.txt') do (
  start command_two with arguments as %%i to %%n
)

for /f "tokens=1-6 delims=," %%i in ('type file4.txt') do (
  start COMMAND_TWO with arguments as %%i to %%n
)

pause
```

The point here is 
I want COMMAND_ONE to be executed first and after that is complete i want the loops to execute in concurrent manner and only one cmd window should be open providing status like ITERATION_1 OF LOOP_1 is complete and ITERATION_2 OF LOOP_3 is complete and so on....

Or just a single line ALL LOOPS COMPLETED at the end of all loops completed in the single cmd window.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could perhaps just run something like this:

```
@echo off
start "" /b /wait COMMAND_ONE
set "files=file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt file4.txt"

for %%a in (%files%) do (
  for /f "tokens=1,* delims=," %%i in (%%a) do (
  start "" /b /wait COMMAND_TWO with arguments as %%i to %%n
 )
)
```

`/b` simply starts a command without a new window while `/wait` will wait for the command/program to finish before lanching the next one.

So Commands explained in order:

Set all files in a variable, loop through the files performing the required commands, while waiting on each to complete before going to the next one.

We also do not need to use `tokens=1-6` as `tokens=1,*` is a better option. From `cmd.exe` see:

```
for /?
start /?
set /?
```

Comment: This answer help a lot, and coming to my problem i want the second for loop iterations to be executed in concurrent fashion, which means if each file contains two lines and there are total of 3 files then all the 6 iterations should be executed concurrently. and after all the execution is complete i want some kind of hint on terminal showing that execution of script is complete